# Browser showing element at wrong posiition

Tags: html

I made a simple html file. but while running this on browser and view source code on browser it shows different DOM structure, table get nested in labels.  Why the DOM structure is different than the original source code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student Details</title>
<head>
<body style="font-family:sans-serif;">
    <center>
        <div id='add_student'>
            <form>
                <lable for="tot" >Name:</label>
                <input type='text' id='tot'>
                <lable for='sex'>Sex:</label>
                <select id="sex">
                    <option value=''>Select</option>
                    <option value='Male'>Male</option>
                    <option value='Female'>Female</option>
                </select>
                <lable for='section'>Section:</label>
                <input type="radio" name="section" id='section' value="A">A 
                <input type="radio" name="section" id='section' value="B">B
                <input type="button" id="add_button" value="Add">
            </form>
            <hr>

        <table style="text-align: center;">
            <th>
                <td width='120px' text-align='center'>Name</td>
                <td width='120px' text-align='center'>Sex</td>
                <td width='120px' text-align='center'>Section</td>
                <td width='120px' text-align='center'>Click</td>
            </th>
        </table>
        <div id='list_div'> 


        </div>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="underscore-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="backbone.js"></script>
        <script type="text/template" id='list_template'>
        <tr>
            <td width='120px' text-align='center' ><%= name %></td>
            <td width='120px' text-align='center'><%= sex %></td>
            <td width='120px' text-align='center'><%= section %></td>
            <td width='120px'><button id='del_but' value='Delete'>Click</button></td>
        </tr>
        </script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </center>
    <script></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You got this `tr` tag where it does not have a table wrapping them

Comment: @Huangism — It is inside a script element. It isn't treated as HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid (e.g. `<lable for="tot" >` is misspelt so elements are nested inside it because you don't have an end tag that actually matches it, and you have a `<th>` wrapping `<td>` elements instead of a `<thead>` wrapping `<th>` elements).

Write valid HTML. Test it using [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Answer (score 0):

You HTML is completely off. In the first table, you have `<td>`s in a `<th>`.

The right structure for a table is:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>header</th>
     <td>data</td>
     <td>data</td>
     (more tds...)
   </tr>
   (more trs...)
</table>
```